# Why toString() on an Object instance (which is null) is not throwing NPE?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Consider below one :

```
Object nothingToHold = null;

System.out.println(nothingToHold);  //  Safely prints 'null'
```

Here, Sysout must be expecting String. 
So toString() must be getting invoked on instance.

So why null.toString() works awesome?  Is Sysout taking care of this?

EDIT : Actually I saw this weird thing with the append() of StringBuilder. So tried with Sysout. Both behave in the same way. So is that method also taking care?

Comment: because `null` is not an object thus have no properties nor methods. `println()` requires `Object`, not `String` and checks if it is `null` by itself.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`PrintWriter`'s `println(Object)` (which is the method called when you write `System.out.println(nothingToHold)`) calls `String.valueOf(x)` as explained in the Javadoc:

```
/**
 * Prints an Object and then terminates the line.  This method calls
 * at first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value,
 * then behaves as
 * though it invokes <code>{@link #print(String)}</code> and then
 * <code>{@link #println()}</code>.
 *
 * @param x  The <code>Object</code> to be printed.
 */
public void println(Object x)
```

`String.valueOf(Object)` converts the null to "null":

```
/**
 * Returns the string representation of the <code>Object</code> argument.
 *
 * @param   obj   an <code>Object</code>.
 * @return  if the argument is <code>null</code>, then a string equal to
 *          <code>"null"</code>; otherwise, the value of
 *          <code>obj.toString()</code> is returned.
 * @see     java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
public static String valueOf(Object obj)
```

Comment: Just to be clear  `object.toString()` will guarantee an NPE if the object is null. Try it out for yourself. `System.out.println()` works on the object's reference to start with. PrintWriter knows when a null reference is passed, so it will pass gracefully and print out `null`. But if you try and call `toString()` from `null` it will surely throw NPE.

Answer (score 8):

The [`PrintStream#println(Object s)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.println%28java.lang.Object%29) method invokes the [`PrintStream#print(String s)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.print%28java.lang.String%29) method, which first checks is the if the argument is `null` and if it is, then just sets `"null"` to be printed as a plain `String`.

However, what is passed to the `.print()` method is `"null"` as `String`, because the `String.valueOf(String s)` returns `"null"` before the `.print()` method being invoked.

```
public void print(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        s = "null";
    }
    write(s);
}
```

Comment: `println(Object)` would be called. It's not a `String` variable, it's an `Object` the compiler does not look inside the value to decide what to call. The only time this would be true if is it was called list so: `println(null)`

Comment: So now it follows that this calls the `String.valueOf` and it is this that introduces the `"null"` string.

Comment: @weston - Ya. You are right :).. I had tried by passing `null` directly to custom methods. Once you assign the reference, it will use the *actual* reference :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Object nothingToHold = null;
   System.out.println(nothingToHold != null ? nothingToHold : "null String or any thing else");
```

This will display output if the nothingToHold(Object) not equals to null, otherwise it prints the message as **"null String or any thing else"**

Answer (score -2):

Here is documentation for `println()`

> Prints a string followed by a newline. The string is converted to an
>   array of bytes using the encoding chosen during the construction of
>   this stream. The bytes are then written to the target stream with
>   write(int).
>
> If an I/O error occurs, this stream's error state is set to true.

`NULL` can convert to bytes.